# Animated navigation-bar doesn't work

Tags: javascript, animation, navigation, toggle

I have a problem with my navigation dropout-menu. My result should be that if I click on a div, that the dropout-menu continuously will vary from height (0px to 400px and back). This means that I have to use a if-statement. The problem is that the dropout-menu only works the first time, but I click again, the height stays at 400px, so the if-statement isn't correct I think.

HTML:

```
<div id="menuIcon" onclick="openMenu()">
    <div id="bar"> </div>
    <div id="bar"> </div>
    <div id="bar"> </div>
    <div id="bar"> </div>
</div>

<div id="dropBar"> 
    <ul>
        <li> Portfolio </li>
        <li> About me </li>
        <li> Contact </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#dropBar {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: white;
    height: 0px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.3s;
}
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
function openMenu() {
        var x = document.getElementById('dropBar');

        if (x.style.height = "0px") {
            x.style.height = "400px";
        } else {
            x.style.height = "0px";
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `if` statement you shouldn't use single equality sign. Use `===` equality operator like this:

```
if (x.style.height === "0px") {
   x.style.height = "400px";
}
```

With this little change, your function works:
https://jsfiddle.net/rgbgtL08/

Answer (score 1):

First of all, with a single = you're assigning not comparing
Then you should use clientHeight instead of style.height which returns the CssStyleDeclaration

```
function openMenu() {
        var x = document.getElementById('dropBar');

        // double == for comparison
        // clientHeight returns a number
        if (x.clientHeight == 0) { 
          //do some
        } else {
          //dome sone else
        }
}
```

**note**
clientHeight includes padding in the calc

Comment: Thank you, it's working. I used the x.clientHeight in if (....) and x.style.height in else (...)